# How to interpreate Reliability Diagrams?

Tags: probability, forecasting, reliability

In general the interpretation of reliability diagrams isn't a problem for me, to identify if a forecast is over- or underestimated. But in this dataset which contains different product probabilities in comparison with real purchases, my generated diagrams confusing me a bit.

Is there a general bias-problem in the dataset? Or do I sth. wrong? Or how to interpret such a plot?

[image: https://imgur.com/a/cxGjn]